# Header redirect doesn't work

Tags: php

I am using PHPmailer for sending a mail. I use the same script on each website. But suddenly, header redirect doesn't work and I really have no idea why...

Cut of the code is below, I appreciate every advice, thanks!

EDIT: FULL CODE ADDED

```
<?php
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

if (isset($_POST['odeslat'])){
  $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "pdf");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

$jmeno = $_POST['jmeno'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
$text = $_POST['zprava'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();


//From email address and name
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->From = "info@mail.com";
$mail->FromName = "MAIL";

//To address and name

$mail->addAddress("yourmail@mail.com"); //Recipient name is optional
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Server email";
$mail->Body = "<p><strong>Jméno:</strong> $jmeno</p>
<p><strong>E-mail:</strong> $email</p>
<p><strong>Telefon:</strong> $telefon</p>
<p><strong>Text:</strong> $text</p>
";
$mail->AltBody = "Jméno: $jmeno \n
E-mail: $email \n
Telefon: $telefon \n
Text: $text\n
";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
   header ("Location: http://mypage.com/dotaznik.php?e=1");
   exit();
} 
else 
{
header ("Location: http://mypage.com/dotaznik.php?o=1");
exit();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Check if there isn't any string sent before your header statement.

Comment: add this http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php what does it show; headers sent?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte well it's just seems weird to me, because as I said, I use exactly this script every time, when I want to send a mail from website. And now, it doesn't work.. I mean, it sends the email, but it doesn't redirect... I can show whole code here, if it will help

Comment: i'm out of this loop then

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've added full code

Comment: `var_dump($mail->send);` if false start debugging

Comment: @nogad it wrote "NULL" to me

Answer (score 1):

Just Use this code:

```
 <?php
 require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

 if (isset($_POST['odeslat'])){
 $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "pdf");
 $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $extension = end($temp);

$jmeno = $_POST['jmeno'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
$text = $_POST['zprava'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();


 //From email address and name
 $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
 $mail->From = "info@mail.com";
 $mail->FromName = "MAIL";

 //To address and name

 $mail->addAddress("yourmail@mail.com"); //Recipient name is optional
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);

 //Send HTML or Plain Text email
 $mail->isHTML(true);

 $mail->Subject = "Server email";
 $mail->Body = "<p><strong>Jméno:</strong> $jmeno</p>
 <p><strong>E-mail:</strong> $email</p>
 <p><strong>Telefon:</strong> $telefon</p>
 <p><strong>Text:</strong> $text</p>
 ";
 $mail->AltBody = "Jméno: $jmeno \n
 E-mail: $email \n
 Telefon: $telefon \n
 Text: $text\n
 ";

 if(!$mail->send()) 
 {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';  
  echo 'window.location.href = "http://mypage.com/dotaznik.php?e=1"';
  echo '</script>';

 } 
 else 
 {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';  
  echo 'window.location.href = "http://mypage.com/dotaznik.php?o=1"';
  echo '</script>';
 }
 }
 ?>
```